# How does git push heroku master save file/folder data in heroku server's db

Tags: python, django, git, heroku

I was trying to understand and replicate git push myserver master in my Django project but didn't understand , how to integrate git push myserver master similar to git push Heroku master.

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think they have a git repository on their side with a hook that catches whenever stuff gets pushed there.

See Server Side hooks here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks